# Removing duplicate IEnumerable<T> from IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, linq

How to remove duplicate content from a given collection of collections? not taking order into account.

for eg.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Collection = [{1,2,3} , {2,1,3}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,2}]
```

should be

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Collection = [{1,2,3} , {1,1,2}, {1,2,2}] // [ {2,1,3}, {1,1,2}, {1,2,2}] is also valid
```

** Edit **

I understand, for IEnumerables E1 and E2  I could do something like this to find the duplicates:

```
bool equal = (E1.Count() == E2.Count() && (!E1.Except(E2).Any() || !E2.Except(E1).Any()))

if(equal)
{
    //Do something
}
```

However, how to do something similar for

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything already? What are your ideas of solving this? This is not a code writing service. SO expects you to show some effort before you come and ask a specific question.

Comment: Please provide some code that compiles and show your previous efforts.

Comment: You can find this thread quite useful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339317/find-duplicate-in-a-list-of-a-list-of-integers/339318#339318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to build a new list, containing only unique items. Your check does
not work for all edge cases (e.q your check is successful for `{1, 1, 2} == {1, 2, 3}`, because value types can only be compared for equality, not identity).

The easiest way is to sort the collection and than use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`

```
public static class Helper
{
   public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Unique(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> source)
   {
      var list = new List<List<int>>(); // sorted reference list.

      foreach (var toCompare in source)
      {
         var toComp = toCompare.OrderBy(x => x).ToList(); // prevent multiple enumerations.
         if (!list.Any(item => toComp.SequenceEqual(item)))
         {
            list.Add(toComp);
            yield return toCompare; // return the unsorted one!
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The usage

```
var unique = collection.Unique();
```

How does the code above work:

We keep a reference list of all returned items, but the reference list is sorted. Then we enumerate the source list, sort every item and check if it is already in our reference list, if not we add the sorted item to the reference list and `yield return` the unsorted original item.